# C++: Matrix class

Tags: c++, class, matrix

Somebody (thank you) posted a matrix class construct for me so that I can resize it dynamically.

I tried to enhance it so that I could get and set individual values.

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : _matrix(rows, std::vector<float>(cols))
    {
        for (unsigned long r=0;r<rows+1;r++)
        {
            vector <float>nRow;

            nRow.resize(cols+1);

            for (unsigned long i=0;i<cols+1)
            {
                  nRow[i]=0;//initialize to zero
            }

            _matrix.push_back(nRow);

        }
    }
    // this is my own attempt to access the items:
    float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) : _matrix[row][col];

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> _matrix;
};
```

I thought I could then access individual items like this:

```
Matrix m(100,100);
m[5,5]=15;
```

But I guess the lines

```
float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) : _matrix[row][col];
```

and

```
m[5,5]=15;
```

are wrong. They don't compile with various errors.

Comment: You've made a *function* (sort of) called `Value`, so it would be `m.Value(5,5);`, but your `Value` definition is not correct either.

Comment: Not to poo on your parade, but there are libraries to do matrix math/structure management (free ones!). Eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and others: (http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library). Reimplementing the wheel is a good educational effort, so if you want to go down that path, have fun!

Comment: Thank you. I would also like to stay independend from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is `float Value() : floatValue;` a valid Visual-C++ statement?

Comment: Can somebody tell me why the line  float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) : _matrix[row][col]; does not want to compile? It tells me that "; is missing".

Comment: As expected – see my previous comment - `float Value() : floatValue;` is not a valid statement. Try `float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) { return _matrix[row][col]; }`

Comment: Try `float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) const { return _matrix[row][col]; }`

Comment: @VictorK Don't you mean  float &Value(size_t row,size_t col) { return _matrix[row][col]; } instead?

Comment: That's if you want to be able to overwrite the value in the matrix outside of the class. My function is read-only. You may even keep both for two occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this code:

```
float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) : _matrix[row][col];
```

This is not a valid c++ declaration. An initializer list is only valid for constructor, which, definitively, this is not the case.

Also, you cant use this kind of object construction call:  `m[5,5]`. Brackets operator must have only one parameter.

To solve your problem, I suggest you to use the operator overload `operator()`. It can have any number of parameter, so, substitute your previous function by:

```
float& operator()(unsigned long row, unsigned long col)
{
    return _matrix[row][col];
}
```

Now, you can make calls like that:

```
m(5, 5) = 15;
b = m(5,5);
```

The drawback is that you are exposing, throught this operator, the internals of your class, which break the encapsulation principle.

Answer (score 1):

You have not overloaded the `[]` operator (Which I don't suggest).  You should be accessing through the function `Value()`.  So:

```
m.Value(5,5);
```

Also,

```
float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col) : _matrix[row][col];
```

Is not a function or a function shorthand that I know of.  It should be:

```
float Value(unsigned long row,unsigned long col)
{ 
   return _matrix[row][col]
}
```